# validation for dynamically created input without using form

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

i am newbie. i want to validate my dynamically created text fields.
unfortunately i couldnt use `<form>` as i am using it in django. i could have used jquery validator if i had used `<form>`. now how do i validate these fields.
my simple code looks like

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".errMsg").hide();
var data = "";
for(var i =0;i<5;i++){
data = data + "Name : <input type='text' id='name"+i+"' class='required' > Age : <input type='text' id='age"+i+"' class='required' ><br>";
}
$("#mytable").html(data);
$("#clickbtn").click(function(){
    for(var j=0;j<5;j++){
        if($("#name"+j).val() == ""){
                alert(j);
            $("#name"+j).focus();
            $(".errMsg").show();
        }
        if($("#age"+j).val() == ""){
            $("#age"+j).focus();
            $(".errMsg").show();
        }
       if(isNan($("#age"+j).val())){
            $("#age"+j).focus();
            $(".errMsg1").show();
        }
    }
});

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Register here</h1>
<div id="mytable"></div>
<button id="clickbtn">click</button>
<div class="errMsg">This is required</div> 
<div class="errMsg">Invalid age</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

i want to validate all the fields and if field is empty i want to highlight everything and display error msg under that texbox.
in this code i could focus only last textbox. how to do it for all.

Please help me.. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isNan is typo error. It should be isNaN.

And please return false in every condition so the script execution will stop there and that particular element will focused.

Please check below snippet for more understanding.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".errMsg").hide();
  var data = "";
  for(var i =0;i<5;i++){
    data = data + "Name : <input type='text' id='name"+i+"' class='required' > Age : <input type='text' id='age"+i+"' class='required' ><br>";
  }
  $("#mytable").html(data);
  $("#clickbtn").on('click', function(){
    for(var j=0;j<5;j++){
      if($("#name"+j).val() == ""){
        $("#name"+j).focus();
        $(".errMsg").show();
        return false;
      }
      if($("#age"+j).val() == ""){
        $("#age"+j).focus();
        $(".errMsg").show();
        return false;
      }
      if(isNaN($("#age"+j).val())){
        $("#age"+j).focus();
        $(".errMsg1").show();
        return false;
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mytable"></div>
<button id="clickbtn">click</button>
<div class="errMsg">This is required</div> 
<div class="errMsg">Invalid age</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".errMsg").hide();
var data = "";
for(var i =0;i<5;i++){
data = data + "Name : <input type='text' id='name"+i+"' class='required' > Age : <input type='text' id='age"+i+"' class='required' ><br>";
}
$("#mytable").html(data);
$("#clickbtn").on('click', function(){
    for(var j=0;j<5;j++){
    if($("#name"+j).val() == ""){
            alert(j);
        $("#name"+j).focus();
        $(".errMsg").show();
    }
    if($("#age"+j).val() == ""){
        $("#age"+j).focus();
        $(".errMsg").show();
    }
   if(isNan($("#age"+j).val())){
        $("#age"+j).focus();
        $(".errMsg1").show();
    }
}
});

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Register here</h1>
<div id="mytable"></div>
<button id="clickbtn">click</button>
<div class="errMsg">This is required</div> 
<div class="errMsg">Invalid age</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code this will may be help you out

```
 $(document).on('click', '#clickbtn',function (){
   //Write your code
})
```

Comment: i tried this, same problem.. only last text box will be focused.. i want all to be focused

Comment: $("body").on("click", "#clickbtn", function () {
    });

Comment: You mean you want to highlight all at same time ?

Comment: yes.. displaying error msg at the bottom of textbox.. i know focus cannot be done for all the textbox, only one at  a time.. but highlight can be done i guess with error msg